# Python Reflection and Type Conversion

Tags: python, reflection, type-conversion, introspection, python-datamodel

In Python, functions like str(), int(), float(), etc. are generally used to perform type conversions.  However, these require you to know at development time what type you want to convert to.  A subproblem of some Python code I'm trying to write is as follows:

Given two variables, `foo` and `bar`, find the type of `foo`.  (It is not known at development time, as this is generic code.)  Then, attempt to convert `bar` to whatever type `foo` is.  If this cannot be done, throw an exception.

For example, let's say you call the function that does this `conv`.  Its signature would look like

```
def conv(foo, bar) :
    # Do stuff.
```

It would be called something like:

```
result = conv(3.14, "2.718")  # result is now 2.718, as a float.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `foo.__class__` to get the type of `foo`. Then call it to convert bar to the type of foo:

```
def conv(foo, bar) :
    return foo.__class__(bar)
```

Of course, this only works if the type of `foo` has a constructor that knows how to convert bar.

Comment: Impressive.  I would have never thought it would be that incredibly easy.  Also surprising (I'm new to Python and used to closer to the metal languages) is that it works with builtins.

Comment: Partially incorrect. foo.__class__ is only the type of foo if foo is a new-style object. Otherwise, it's only the class.

Comment: Only incorrect inasmuch I said 'type' when class would be more precise. But he needs the class for this conversion. And in Python 3, the difference is gone anyway.

Answer (score 16):

that would be best:

```
type(foo)(bar)
```

Comment: Only in Python 3.0. In Python 2.x, this will work only for "new-style classes" and builtins.

Answer (score 0):

```
type(foo)
```

is definitely the best, if you want to check a type then "type" is the best method, and I am on `python 2.7 - 3.2.2, type()` works perfectly.